# gps sensor in gazebo 1.9

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to attach a gps sensor to a gazebo model of a robot I have.
I use a robot.urdf.xacro file to describe the robot and a robot.gazebo file to describe the sensors.
I don't know how to implement the gps. Is there any tutorial or information about it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6220/gps-sensor-in-gazebo-1.9/) by [arenillas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/799/arenillas/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2014-05-20**:
Have a look at http://wiki.ros.org/hector_gazebo_plugins#GazeboRosGps

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/799/arenillas/) on 2014-05-20**:
I am trying to use it but I don't know how to implement it in the .gazebo file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can include it in the URDF model of your robot using the `plugin` tag like this:

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="novatel_gps_sim" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so">
    <alwaysOn>1</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
    <bodyName>base_footprint</bodyName>
    <topicName>fix</topicName>
    <velocityTopicName>fix_velocity</velocityTopicName>
    <drift>5.0 5.0 5.0</drift>
    <gaussianNoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</gaussianNoise>
    <velocityDrift>0 0 0</velocityDrift>
    <velocityGaussianNoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</velocityGaussianNoise>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

[Here](https://github.com/fsuarez6/labrob/blob/master/labrob_description/urdf/labrob.urdf.xacro#L202) you can find a working example.

---

Originally posted by [Francisco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/314/francisco/) with karma: 143 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/799/arenillas/) on 2014-05-21**:
Thanks. It worked perfectly.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-05-21**:
Could you please mark this answer as already answered by clicking the check button at the left?